# eliminate FIX layer to increase performance

Tags: fix-protocol

does it makes sense? a protocol designed for speed as well as resiliency that eliminates the FIX layer for high performance order execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAST protocol is intended to be a "faster" version of the FIX protocol. The quantity of extra processing it requires means that it is only faster "on the wire" however and so will not be very effective for those with boxes at exchange. @dumbcoder is, as usual, correct about optimization and high-powered machines being the best way of reducing latencies. That FIX isn't inherently slow, dependent on your implementation, is also very important. Sell-side and HFT implementations are much faster than the cheaper ones used by the hedgies and investors.

Comment: I should add that for low latency applications it is very important to look where the latency has greatest effect. We found that it was actually when we started saving to the database that we had our greatest performance hit. This had nothing to do with which protocol we chose as we had to save the same information whatever happened to fill out our executions. The key is actually to choose an industry standard method of communication and then optimize as much as you can. The problem of developing any new protocol is that you have to get people to adopt it or you can't talk to anyone!

Comment: How does FPGA corresponds to it?

Comment: FPGA is a totally different conversation. FPGA is the PLATFORM that is used, not the PROTOCOL. Using an FPGA board entails programming your trading/routing logic onto a microprocessor (the FPGA chip) so that you can avoid the PCI bus and the rest of the stuff involved with receiving/sending orders with an OS.  You can use FIX or FAST or ITCH or anything else to send/receive orders with an FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether exchanges should adopt non-fix protocols for receiving market messages?  Some already have alternatives (e.g. NASDAQ's ITCH and OUCH).  But they don't 'eliminate' the FIX layer - they still provide the same function, they just go about it in a different way.

FIX actually doesn't have to be all that slow - if you treat messages as byte arrays (instead of one big string) and then only get out exactly what you need (which, for order acceptances, fills, etc., can be very few tags), then FIX is really not that bad.

The key selling point of FIX is that it is an industry standard.  Exchanges are free to develop their own proprietary protocols which can be higher performance, but the fact that everyone can write to a single protocol is a big deal (even if it is not always implemented in the most efficient manner).

Comment: so it is not FIX that is used in highest performance HFT trading?

Comment: @cf16 - No they use FIX, but use powerful machines and highly optimized and fast FIX message generators. Most banks use commercial ones or their in house FIX messaging libraries.

Comment: Some will use FIX - I'm a fund manager and we do HFT and we have a proprietary FIX engine that we use.  We don't, however, have a focus on ultra-low latency. If we did, we would likely write directly to each exchanges 'Native API' which would theoretically give us performance gains. The only problem with this type of optimization is that measuring actual efficiency gains is more complicated than you would think which means that it is difficult to justify the extra work unless latency is your primary focus.

Answer (score 0):

Another angle which should be explored is whether there is a separate communication channel for the protocol or one is implemented as a wrapper on top of other. 
Working on FIX is definitely an advantage that implementation remains portable with slight modification across exchanges.